# resignFirstResponder/endEditing causes bad access

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I am creating an application which creates forms dynamically from the data available from web services.So I am adding a View programmatically each time when I need to present a page which may consist of a label for question,textfield for answer and a text area for comments.My problem is I have applied validations to the textfield in textfield delegate methods.And when I try to dismiss the keyboard by using return key , it leads to bad access with the following message

*** -[UITextField isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb9f8f56390.

the delegate method is as follows:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn");
    isKeyBoardPresent = NO;

    if([textField becomeFirstResponder])
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I have enabled zombie in my project.By that I got the above line.But I am not able to find out what the problem is.Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your if statement from:

`if([textField becomeFirstResponder])
[textField resignFirstResponder];`

to:

`if([textField isFirstResponder]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}`